# refrencing node in another content type based on his two fields

Tags: entities

i am working on a medical site. i have 3 content type drug, pharmacy, drug price.

to enter the price of a drug for a pharmacy i use drug price content type

here i take a reference of drug content type for drug name and it is working fine and populate nodes  title of drug type

and after that i want to add this price of drug to any particular pharmacy, because i have many pharamcy with the same name in differen area. so i want two add two fields in drug price content type, one for zipcode and another for pharmacy title. both of them are already there in pharmacy content type . so i want that entity refernce populate only the pharamcies based on zipcode given in the upper filed  by admin.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0db1o14md9

please check the screenshots

Regards

Comment: If you have updates to previous questions please edit the new information into those  instead of asking them again. Thanks

Comment: pls check my answer on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84108/why-does-the-node-reference-module-search-only-for-node-titles/84275#84275 and first install tokens and autonode title module for title to get values for location and zip

Comment: yes i check your answer and follow all steps by installing tokens and autonode title module. but it just change the title of the node but i don't want to change the title becasue i am using this title in many other places. i only want that the titles comes in autopopulate based on zipcode entered bu me in the field which is just above this auto complete field . thanks